# Cannot change php.ini settings without restart of machine

Tags: apache-http-server, fedora, php, httpd

I finally found out that I need to the restart my machine to take over some php.ini configuration changes. But I'm wondering why I cannot just restart httpd. What do I have to do that I don't need to restart my machine?

My machine:

- Fedora 29 (actually the default distribution without any special changes)
- PHP 7.2.13 with PHP-FPM (default)
- Apache 2.4.37 (default)
- Configuration of php in /etc/php.ini and /etc/php.d

I detected my problem with xdebug configuration using phpinfo() in the browser. But even if I change short_open_tag in php.ini and I do `sudo systemctl restart httpd` the value is unchanged in the browser. However, on the console (php -i) the value was taken over. But not by httpd, using phpinfo() and the browser. I also tried to restart php-fpm with `sudo systemctl restart php-fpm`, but it did not have an effect.

Since configuration will be correctly used when I restarte the machine, it cannot be a problem with wrong places of configuration files where I have changed things.

So what do I have to do that I don't need to reboot the whole machine? Or what prevents `sudo systemctl restart httpd` using the new configuration?

Comment: "But I'm wondering why I cannot just restart httpd" - Have you tried "sudo systemctl restart" by chance?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27396973/how-to-force-reloading-php-ini-file

Comment: @Ramhound Yes. I have restarted the services - as I have already described. Or what do you mean exactly?

Comment: I suggested you try a very specific command.  You attempted to restart a single service, I suggested, you restart all your services.

Comment: @Ramhound I see. Didn't know that this is possible. However, isn't it also a bit radical? I thought that restarting httpd should be sufficient...

Comment: It is necessary to diagnose which service results in the PHP settings to be refreshed.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, running PHP 7.3.6 on Amazon Linux 2.  Frustrating, but a reboot of the whole server updates settings, whereas using systemctl restart httpd (or systemctl stop / start) does not.